# Is there a way to increase "Jump to Definition" popup in XCode 9.3?

Tags: xcode, xcode9.3

XCode 9.3 updated the "Jump to Definition" popup from
[image: "Jump to Definition" popup in XCode 9.2]

to

[image: "Jump to Definition" popup in XCode 9.3]

Is there a way to increase the height of the popup to display more options instead of scrolling?

Comment: I think no. There is no way to do it.